# Integral $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hi I'm trying to solve this integral Fourier Transform
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^{3/2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi|k|}(1+i)  (-1+\text{sgn}(k))
$$
where sgn(k)$=1$ for k>1 and $-1$ for k<1.
I am trying to use residues.  Thanks there is a singularity at $x=0$.  We can try and write
$$
e^{ikx}=\cos x+i\sin x
$$
but I don't think it will help.  IT will be nice to use a contour with $e^{ikx}$ instead.  Thanks

Comment: I think you'll be using the famous keyhole contour. Break in the integral up into $(0,\infty)$ and $(-infty,0)$. You should be able to write the latter in terms of the former. To actually compute the former, draw a keyhole (sometimes called a pacman) contour and be mindful of the branch cut. Without actually working it out, I believe this is the typical crank to turn for this type of integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{s \equiv \ic x\quad\imp\quad x = -\ic s = \expo{3\ic\pi/2}s}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty + \ic 0^{+}}^{\infty + \ic 0^{+}}
{\expo{\ic kx} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x&=
\Theta\pars{-k}\int_{-0^{+} - \ic\infty}^{-0^{+} + \ic\infty}
{\expo{\ic k\pars{-\ic s}} \over \pars{\expo{3\ic\pi/2}s}^{3/2}}\,\pars{-\ic\,\dd s}
\\[3mm]&=
\Theta\pars{-k}\pars{-\ic\expo{-9\ic\pi/4}}
\int_{0^{+} -\ic\infty}^{0^{+} + \ic\infty}{\expo{\verts{k}s} \over \expo{-3\ic\pi/2}s^{3/2}}\,\dd s
\\[3mm]&=\Theta\pars{-k}{\root{2} \over 2}\pars{-1 + i}
\int_{0^{+} -\ic\infty}^{0^{+} + \ic\infty}s^{-3/2}\expo{\verts{k}s}\,\dd s\tag{1}
\end{align}

> $$
> \int_{0^{+} - \ic\infty}^{0^{+} + \ic\infty}s^{-3/2}\expo{\verts{k}s}\,\dd s
> =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\pars{%
> {\cal I}_{+} + {\cal I}_{-}}\tag{2}
> $$

\begin{align}
{\cal I}_{+}&=-\int_{-\infty + \ic\epsilon}^{\ic\epsilon}
\pars{-x}^{-3/2}\expo{-3\ic\pi/2}\expo{\verts{k}x}\,\dd x=
-\ic\int_{-\ic\epsilon}^{\infty - \ic\epsilon}x^{-3/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-2\ic\pars{-\ic\epsilon}^{-1/2}
+ 2\ic\verts{k}\int_{-\ic\epsilon}^{\infty - \ic\epsilon}x^{-1/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\root{2}\pars{-1 + i}\epsilon^{-1/2}
+ 2\ic\verts{k}\int_{-\ic\epsilon}^{\infty - \ic\epsilon}x^{-1/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x\tag{3}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}_{-}&=-\int_{-\ic\epsilon}^{-\infty - \ic\epsilon}
> \pars{-x}^{-3/2}\expo{3\ic\pi/2}\expo{\verts{k}x}\,\dd x=
> -\ic\int_{\ic\epsilon}^{\infty + \ic\epsilon}x^{-3/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-2\ic\pars{\ic\epsilon}^{-1/2}
> +2\ic\verts{k}\int_{\ic\epsilon}^{\infty + \ic\epsilon}x^{-1/2}\expo{-\verts{k}kx}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\root{2}\pars{1 - i}\epsilon^{-1/2}
> + 2\ic\verts{k}\int_{\ic\epsilon}^{\infty + \ic\epsilon}x^{-1/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x\tag{4}
> \end{align}

We replace $\pars{3}$ and $\pars{4}$ in $\pars{2}$. In the limit
$\epsilon \to 0^{+}$:
\begin{align}
\Theta\pars{-k}\int_{0^{+} - \ic\infty}^{0^{+} + \ic\infty}s^{3/2}\expo{\verts{k}s}\,\dd s
&=\Theta\pars{-k}\bracks{4\ic\verts{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-\verts{k}x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=4\ic\root{\verts{k}}\Theta\pars{-k}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\Gamma\pars{1/2} = \root{\pi}}}
\\[3mm]&=\Theta\pars{-k}\bracks{4\ic\root{\pi\verts{k}}}
=-2\ic\bracks{-1 + \sgn\pars{k}}\,\root{\pi\verts{k}}\tag{5}
\end{align}

> We'll replace $\pars{5}$ in $\pars{1}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic kx} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x}&=
> {\root{2} \over 2}\pars{-1 + i}\braces{%
> -2\ic\bracks{-1 + \sgn\pars{k}}\,\root{\pi\verts{k}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large\root{2\pi\verts{k}}\pars{1 + i}\bracks{-1 + \sgn\pars{k}}}
> \end{align}